# How can I create a dynamic weekly schedule in HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, tabular

It's simple to create a table based layout for a weekly calendar with 7 columns for each day of the week and various rows for each hour of the week. I have no problem creating that. The hard part is filling in this table with daily 'events' dynamically (I'm not even sure how I would do this statically).

The user will have access to a list of 'events' that they would like to add to their weekly schedule. And they need to be added dynamically to the webpage. Each event has a specific start and end time, and may occur on more than one day of the week. I'm not sure how I could possibly add these 'events' to my table layout without getting into a bunch of rowspan problems ( a lot of the events are various lengths and span different hours ). It would be easy if each event was always 1 hour long, but that's not the case.

I was thinking of making each day a respective table with a hidden hour column. I still feel like this will result in a huge mess. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully see the question.  However, have you thought of using Google Calendar or some other online calendar product?

Comment: Google Calendar or other online calendar is out of the question. I need to create a unique weekly schedule for the user based on a list of 'events'. They choose the 'events' they want and then the webpage needs to update itself to display how the weekly schedule for that user will look like. I'm also going to need to deal with things like conflicts (overlapping events).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?

I think this covers all your concerns.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of any fullcalendar alternatives?

Comment: @whoabackoff - No not really. There's Google Cal and Apple's Mobile Me, but other than that, I'm not aware of anything else. Good luck!